# Get the specific values from variables from the application output (exe file) which is in csv format in python

Tags: python, string, function, csv, get

I want the values of start1 , end1, start2 , end2 from the below program. How to get that. I tried using get() but as its str , I get the error " 'str' object has no attribute 'get' "  Self.bin is the exe file path. {{{{ It can be a similar question , I tried using them , but couldn't get the result. Please provide the solution for the below python code. Before closing my question. Many Thanks }}}}

```
    def run(self ) :
     query = self.args.query
     target = self.args.target
     complete = str(self.bin + ' -q ' + query + ' -t ' + target +' --outMode=C -n 1')
     ps = s.Popen(str(complete),  stdin = s.PIPE, stdout = s.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
     (stdout, stderr) = ps.communicate()
     self.b1 = stdout
     print("B1: \n")
     print(self.b1)

    self.block_b1(self.b1, self.b2, self.b3)



    def block_b1(self, b1, b2, b3): ############get values from above method 
     print(self.b1.get("start1"))
     print(self.b1.get("start2"))      
     print(self.b1.get('end1'))
     print(self.b1.get('end2'))



    output of self.b1 lookslike this :
B1:

id1;start1;end1;id2;start2;end2;subseqDP;hybridDP;E
target;39;45;query;98;104;UCCUGGA&UCCAGGA;(((((((&)))))));-4.37
```

**I want result as below**:

```
39

98

45

104
```

Answer (score 0):

ok first do this

```python
result_array=self.b1.split(';')
res=[]
for item in result_array:
    if item.isdigit():
      res.push(item)

for i in res:
   print(i)
```